# How can I access all drawables in android?

Tags: android

Only some drawables are accessible via the 

`<ImageButton
src="@+android:drawable/`

syntax. For example expander_ic_maximized is not accessible, yet its clearly at 
http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

its so frustrating to have to download the drawables and manually put them in my drawables folder....any ideas how to get around this???

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Android SDK has all images unpacked in the `%SDK-FOLDER%/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable-*` folder. Just pick desired file and put it into your app resource.

Comment: +1 In my case I found it in sdks 1.5 & 1.6 not in 2.2 & others

Comment: You still have to copy over for each resolution...gotta be a better way

Answer (score 6):

I realize it's a bit more work, but as a workaround you could just set the image resource programatically.

`findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1).setImageResource(android.R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized)`

Comment: nothing different in your approach. its  permissions issue or something... "android.R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized cannot be resolved"

Comment: Those drawables aren't guaranteed to be in the android OS. You shouldn't use them as this could very easily break on different devices.

Comment: I believe it all depends on what your `minSdkVersion` is set to.. but Falmarri is correct, using SDK-specific drawables can exclude certain devices.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to add this in your imports list:

```
import android.R;
```

but i will make your own resources will have an error if you want to use it.
The error will be something like:

> R. cannot be resolved

So, I prefer not to `import android.R` but `import *my.own.package*.R;`

then when I can normally use my own resource with `R.drawable.*something*` without error,
and put `android.R.*something_default*` to use the default android resources.

well, choosing which one to use, depends in what you need.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Find the name of your desired icon (e.g., `ic_menu_preferences`), and paste it into your XML.

For example, to show the settings icon in the option menu, your XML should be:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
```

That's it. No need to copy to drawable folder. Whenever you write `:` sign after `android`, it addresses system resources.

Comment: Not all drawables listed here are available for public use. Do need anything spl like a permission for something to access these drawables ?