# Adapter for RecentCalls Activity

Tags: android, adapter, phone-call

I'm using googles source code to build a recent calls look alike activity. I have to create an app with a custom view of the dialer, recent calls and contacts, so my first step was to create a custom dialer. Then, I created a call log, but the appearance wasn't nice enought so I get google's contacts app package to get the RecentCallsActivity and adapt to my app.

Now, I've got almost the app working, but I have some errors that I don't know how to solve. This is a extract of the code with the most relevant parts to try to solve this errors:

```
public class RecentCallsListActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    ...

    RecentCallsAdapter mAdapter;

    ....

    final class RecentCallsAdapter implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener, View.OnClickListener, Runnable {

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        mAdapter = new RecentCallsAdapter();
        getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);  // The method SetListAdapter (ListAdapter) in the type ListActivity is not aplicable for the arguments (RecentCallsListActivity.RecentCallsAdapter)

        mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(this);
        }

        @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfoIn) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;

    Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getItem(menuInfo.position); //The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type RecentCallsListActivity.RecentCallsAdapter

    ...
```

These are the 2 principal errors. In the original file, the mAdapter is declared the same way and there aren't these errors. 
Also, there are other 2 errors:

```
mAdapter.isGroupHeader(menuInfo.position)
mAdapter.getGroupSize(menuInfo.position)
```

It must be some kind of declaration but I don't know why or what to do.

**UPDATE**

I've solved this extending a class to the adapter thanks to Eugene's answer. But now I have the following problem when implementing some drawables. I know i can't reference to the android.internal.R so the thing would be to find a solution for this:

```
protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupSize,
            boolean expanded) {
        final RecentCallsListItemViews views = (RecentCallsListItemViews) view.getTag();
        int groupIndicator = expanded
                ? com.android.internal.R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized //CANNOT BE RESOLVED
                        : com.android.internal.R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized; //CANNOT BE RESOLVED
        views.groupIndicator.setImageResource(groupIndicator);
        views.groupSize.setText("(" + groupSize + ")");
        bindView(context, view, cursor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter does not implement listadapter interface
Original adapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter, which already implements ListAdapter

```
final class RecentCallsAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter
        implements Runnable, ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener, View.OnClickListener {
```

but your adapter does not.

```
final class RecentCallsAdapter implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener, View.OnClickListener, Runnable
```

You should either extend some class, either implement `ListAdapter` yourself

Other two errors come from same origin - you just don't have such methods, because You haven't implemented them, nor you have extended the class already having them.

Good luck with coding :)

Comment: Yes I know it, but the original file neither does it, so I supposed that it wasn't necesary...

Comment: When implementing this interfaze, it autogenerates functions like getItem(), etc.. What I don't understand is why in the original file there aren't theses functions and it doesn't show error

Comment: Well, I see that the original file extends GroupingListAdapter. I dond't include this because I don't need to group them. I'll try with this first and then I'll have a look at your answer

Comment: There are several base ListAdapter implementations, try to choose one that suits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks. Have a look at the question, I've updated it. Maybe you can help me with this too.

Comment: Please post new question. On your updated question - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uUhXbb0zwgk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673629/how-can-i-access-all-drawables-in-android

Comment: I solve it, just copied from the sdk folder and pasted it on eclipse