# How to set src of ImageView to android yellow (pressed) star

Tags: android

Attempt 1:

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/star_contact"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"/>
```

But it is showing a white hollow star instead of yellow star.

Attempt 2:

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/star_contact"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off_pressed"
  visibility="gone"/>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
resource is not public at src with value '@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off_pressed'
```

Is there a way to fix my 2nd attempt's error?

Is there a way to initially set android resource star image to be pressed?

I appreciate help and willing to tick a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's better to copy drawables from Android and use them, rather than directly use the Android drawables. Take a look at the downloadables from [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4677301/544198) for how to access them as well.

It used to be the advice on the Android Design documents to always do things this way, but that advice seems to be removed. Still, if you're having problems, you can always try this.

Comment: But in my case, I needed the drawables to dynamically correspond to the theme of my app. I may have more than 1 theme.

Comment: More than 1 theme is okay. Just copy the icons to your folder, and use styles to indicate which icon you're using. It'd just as easy as it'd be to use the @android:drawable` folder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a case of data duplication? I think that may work but I am also concerned of efficiency here.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at this drawable

```
android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on
```

This post [here](http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html) has a corresponding icon along with the drawables available in android.R package. So in your case it will be

```
android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
```

I did a test in my device with this imageview

```
 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/star_contact"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
```

It is showing yellow like this: 
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but it just shows the un-hollow version of the star and unfortunately it doesnt make the star yellow.

Comment: ok let me test in my machine whats going on. It should actually work

Comment: It is showing yellow in my htc one with android kitkat.

Comment: well in the case of my Sony Xperia Acro S with Android Jellybean it is not. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the list of drawable that are accessible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html)

If it's not in the list, then you have to add drawables in your project and access from there.