# Where can I find hamburger icon drawable?

Tags: android, android-resources

Where can I find hamburger icon drawable ? Is it present in Android SDK or some Support library ? What is icon drawable id if it is present somewhere mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673629/how-can-i-access-all-drawables-in-android) answer.

Every SDK contains its own package of relevant drawables so you should try and look it up in the relevant SDK. I think it's ICS(Android v4.0).